# How to override equals for two Maps of <String, Object>?

Tags: java, dictionary, equals

I have a class that has a Map<String, Object> field (the keys are Strings, the values are Objects that have correctly implemented the "equals" method for comparison).

I would like to override equals for this class in a way that only returns true if the Maps have equal mappings between keys and values.

Here is my attempt:

```
// Assumes that the Object values in maps have correctly implemented the equals method.
private boolean mapsEqual(Map<String, Object> attributes) 
{
    if (this.attributes_.keySet().size() != attributes.keySet().size() ||
        this.attributes_.values().size() != attributes.values().size())
        return false;
    for (String key : attributes.keySet()) {
        if (!this.attributes_.keySet().contains(key))
            return false;
        if (!this.attributes_.get(key).equals(attributes.get(key)))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, this implementation fails when the same key is added more than once or when a key is removed from the map (the size tests fail for the values, as they count the duplicates and do not resize when values are removed.)

It seems that my situation should be common enough to find information that is relevant to my case, but I could not find any. Is there any legacy code or widely accepted solution to this situation? Any help or working solution is appreciated.

Comment: The `Map` interface forbids duplicate keys or multiple values per key: `A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.` – [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: … also: The `equals` specification already does what you say. Any proper implementation of the interface should therefore already implement `equals` correctly. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use that instead?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, which is correct, it does not resolve my issue with the size of the `keySet()` or `values()` returned by the map. As a solution, I may re-implement my `mapsEqual` above to ignore the sizes of the collections. This is because adding duplicates or removing keys seems to affect the size of the value collection, which makes my above implementation incorrect. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: For your second comment, do you mean that I do not need this method, and can use `map1.equals(map2)` instead? That would be great, but my understanding is that hash maps might be different when their content is the same, resulting in a false negative for the `equals` is `true` case.

Comment: `java.util.HashMap#equals` will call `equals` on its contents. So as long as your keys/values implement `equals` correctly, you should – imho – be fine. I posted an answer and invite you to provide example code that actually shows the supposedly flawed behavior you are experiencing, then we can look into it much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to put this as an answer even though I am not 100% sure it solves your problem (but it's simply not gonna fit in a comment).

First off, to repeat my comments: The `Map` interface forbides that a map has duplicate keys or multiple values per key. Any proper implementation (e.g. `java.util.HashMap`) will therefore not allow this. Typically they will just replace the value if this happens.

Furthermore, the specification for `equals`, to me, seems to be doing what you want. Again, a proper implementation must live up to that specification.

So, what's the point here: If you are writing your own class that is implementing `Map`, then it simply cannot allow duplicate keys (methods like `get` wouldn't make sense anymore). If you are using a built-in implementation such as `HashMap`, it replaces the values anyway.

Now you are saying that you're experiencing size issues with `keySet()` and `values()`. I think you should add example code that will cause this behavior. The following works just fine for me:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Foo", "Bar");

System.out.println(map.keySet().size()); // 1
System.out.println(map.values().size()); // 1

map.put("Foo", "Baz"); // the HashMap will merely replace the old value

System.out.println(map.keySet().size()); // still 1
System.out.println(map.values().size()); // still 1
```

Removing a key will, of course, change the size. I don't see how you consider this a problem based on your explanations so far.

As for `equals`, you may just want to look at the implementation for `HashMap`, which can be found <kbd>[here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractMap.java#AbstractMap.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)</kbd>:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;

    if (!(o instanceof Map))
        return false;
    Map<K,V> m = (Map<K,V>) o;
    if (m.size() != size())
        return false;

    try {
        Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
            K key = e.getKey();
            V value = e.getValue();
            if (value == null) {
                if (!(m.get(key)==null && m.containsKey(key)))
                    return false;
            } else {
                if (!value.equals(m.get(key)))
                    return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException unused) {
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException unused) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Consider the following example:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map1.put("Foo", "Bar");

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map2.put("Foo", "Bar");

System.out.println(map1.equals(map2)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you complain about your maps having duplicate keys... not possible (unless you're using a badly broken implementation).

This should do it:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof MyClass))
        return false;
    MyClass that = (MyClass)o;
    if (map.size() != that.map.size())
        return false;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map) {
        Object a = entry.getValue();
        Object b = that.map.get(entry.getKey());
        if ((a == null ^ b == null) || (a == null && !a.equals(b)))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: One word: NullPonterException.

Comment: @IngoBürk where would that occur? I suppose I'm assuming the value of an entry isn't null, which is reasonable. If not, the reader can modify the code to cater for that. I think this code would work.

Comment: The key can be null (perfectly legal), the value can be null (also perfectly legal), `map` can be null and `that.map` can be null. Have a look at the actual `HashMap` implementation – they certainly disagree with you on what can be null. Besides that I fail to see why you wouldn't just use `map.equals(that.map)`.

Comment: @IngoBürk the key being null won't cause an NPE. OP's code doesn't null check the map, so I assume it's initialized in the declaration. That leaves the value... fine; I've added the code you seem to want to see.

Comment: I removed my down-vote. However, my last point still stands: Why reinvent the wheel and not just use `map.equals(that.map)`?